# recognize start conditions only at one string lex

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, lex

I need to set token like "any character, except beginning of new line". I'm try

```
[^^]
```

but this is not working. Firstly, I need to detect some pattern line:

```
%s arithm secOper
NUMBER  [0-9]+
INTEGER (-?[0-9]+)
ASSIGN [=]
VARY    [A-Za-z][?-i:a-z0-9]{0,15}
ARITHMSIGNS (\+[ ]*|\-[ ]*|\*[ ]*|\/[ ]*)
SPACE   [ ]+
SPACES  [ ]*
ANY [^^]

%%

^{NUMBER}{SPACES}{VARY}{SPACES}{ASSIGN}{SPACES}({VARY}|{INTEGER})   {BEGIN(arithm);}
<arithm>{ANY}{SPACES}{ARITHMSIGNS}/({VARY}|{INTEGER})    {BEGIN(secOper);}
<secOper>{VARY}|{INTEGER}$    {BEGIN(INITIAL);}

%%
```

so string like

```
54  firstVar = 43  * newVar
```

is really true, but if input is:

```
54  firstVar  =  43
 * newVar
```

(2 strings in c-like stream with \n) must be error, but pattern recognize it. I need to recognize all start conditions at one input line. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this the wrong way. This is a grammar problem, not a lexical problem. If newline is significant in your language it should appear explicitly in the grammar, and be returned as a token by the lexer.

Comment: this is little task, not a language,  and I must do it without bison. So if I create token newline and use it, situation doesn't changed.